# prove if $xyk \neq 0$, then: $x^3=3(k+xy)(k-xy-y^3)$ has no integral solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $\gcd(x,y)=1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Show that if $xyk
 \neq 0$, then: $$x^3=3(k+xy)(k-xy-y^3)$$ has no integral solutions.

Any hints? I keep getting lost in my reasoning.

Comment: Where does $z\ne0$ enter into things? Is $k$ supposed to be $z$?

Comment: $(k+xy)(k-xy-y^3)$ must divides by $9$; $y\equiv \pm1\pmod 3$. It's enough

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, how did you get to your "solutions" when Wolfram Alpha could not?

Comment: @robjohn, thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the typo.

Comment: @robjohn, same question, deleted yesterday by this user, posted again. This time i favorited. I also want to know the source of the damned problem.

Comment: @Will Jagy, It is part of a problem that I am trying to solve. On Wolphram Alpha, there are only trivial solutions, I cannot figure how to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing the quadratic formula for $k,$ we find that $k$ is an integer if and only if
$$  12(x+y^2)^3 - 3 y^6  $$ is an integer square.

**IF $y$ IS ZERO THIS MEANS ANY $x = 3 u^2$ WORKS.**

When $y \neq 0,$ call that square $s^2,$ since $s=3t$ we get $  12(x+y^2)^3 - 3 y^6 = 9 t^2, $ or $  4(x+y^2)^3 -  y^6 = 3 t^2. $ The only restrictions are that the variables $x,y,k$ not be zero. It becomes convenient to write $w = x + y^2$ and  $4 w^3 - y^6 = 3 t^2,$ and we are asking whether we must have $w = y^2.$ The best order for this is
$$ \color{red}{  y^6 - 4 w^3 + 3 t^2 = 0.}  $$

From  [COHEN PAGES 396 397](https://books.google.com/books?id=qxCWoFO-oxYC&pg=PA396&lpg=PA396&dq=Here%20we%20will%20say%20that%20two%20nonzero%20rational%20solutions%20%28x,y,z%29%20and%20%28x%27,y%27,z%27%29%20are%20the%20same%20under%20twisted%20projective%20equivalence%20if%20there%20exists&source=bl&ots=2DObObRDcE&sig=SQJSgxN3aeFu_HBKSuWMTYy3kgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIjtORuP_sxgIVSlqICh0aLws-#v=onepage&q=Here%20we%20will%20say%20that%20two%20nonzero%20rational%20solutions%20%28x%2Cy%2Cz%29%20and%20%28x%27%2Cy%27%2Cz%27%29%20are%20the%20same%20under%20twisted%20projective%20equivalence%20if%20there%20exists&f=false), definition of twisted projective middle of page 396, this result is Proposition 6.5.9(3)(d) near the top of page 397,
we find that all solutions are twists of
$$ (-12, 144, \pm 1728).  $$ Taking his $\lambda = -1/12,$ all solutions are equivalent to
$$ (1,1,\mp 1).   $$

Which is to say, the only integer solutions to 
$$ \color{red}{  y^6 - 4 w^3 + 3 t^2 = 0}  $$
have $w = y^2$ and $t = \pm y^3.$ Given $w = x + y^2,$ this means $x=0.$

EDIT: sad, just checked, page 397 is not shown, because that is where the good bits are...part (3)(d) says IF $ab^2 c^3 / 432 = m^6$ is a sixth power, we have the two solutions $(bc,-12bcm^2, \pm36b^2m^3),$ which are unique up to twisted projective equivalence.

The proof, quite short, is also on page 397.

[THIS OTHER REALLY LONG URL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjABahUKEwiVtsXmiO3GAhWPWYgKHdcFDk8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ntmsci.com%2FAjaxTool%2FGetManuscriptByManuscriptId%3FManuscriptId%3D166&ei=UKyuVZXOJo-zoQTXi7j4BA&usg=AFQjCNEDCks-jg8dqPbRMPJotf8uB7d0SQ&sig2=G0VL72dPzutwK_iUqOWrFw&bvm=bv.98476267,d.cGU) is, with any luck, a pdf of a later paper that includes the result. Yep, Theorem 2.5.2, no new solutions occur when allowing Gaussian integers, just the ones Cohen indicated.

Comment: Thanks Will Jagy for your help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure whether I did not fully grasp your elaborate approach but I am a little puzzled by the fact that you wrote that the only integer solutions require that $x=0$. I found out that $( k,x,y)=(3,3,0) $ is a solution as well although trival.

Comment: Cohen mentions solutions including $0$ separately, which is what you expect if the word "projective" is used. Suggest you buy or borrow the book. Also, you are the one who said $x,y,k \neq 0.$